# How to Refresh report after Subreport processing in C#?

Tags: c#, report, rdlc, subreport

I am trying to Refresh my report after subreport processing is over. Till now I have tried RenderingComplete event but its been called before subreport processing.
I also placed reportviewer.RefreshReport in my subreport processing but its showing cross thread run time error.
Any suggestion or code snippet will be very helpful. Thank You.

```
            TDSReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "MyProject.MyReports.MainPage.rdlc";
            TDSReportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(DataSet1);
            TDSReportViewer.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing += new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.SubreportProcessingEventHandler(this.reportViewer1_suberport1);
            this.TDSReportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

And for subreport processing

```
public void reportViewer1_suberport1(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
{
            else if (e.ReportPath == "SubPage1")
            {
                Report.Page1Data.Clear();
                DataTable dt = Report.Page1Data;
                dt.Rows.Add(databasePathInfo.databasePath + "//DynamicImages", GlobalDataClass.Language, GlobalDataClass.UnitSize, GlobalDataClass.Model, "Model Dimensional Images");
                Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource datasource1 = new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
                e.DataSources.Add(datasource1);
            }
}
```

Comment: why do you want to execute refresh in OnSubreportProcessing handler? I've used the same handler to get data for a subreport and it works without any problem. One trick is that I'm guessing what data to get by e.ReportPath and e.DataSourceNames. But if you want to show any data - you can avoid this.

Comment: @Oleska actually my data inside my report is changing and I want to reflect it and it's been done till now by pressing the refresh button.

Comment: would you like to change main report data in subreport processing? Actually all you can do in the subreport processing is to supply data for subreport AFAIK. If you want to get some custom image (or text) and show its value in the main report (or subreport) please try write special method in C# that will do this job and call it from the rdl, like this one <Value>=Namespace.Class.Method("IMAGE_ID")</Value>. You can populate not only text fields, but images too

Comment: No actually my complete report including ,my subreport and mainreport data is changing. The changes are only reflected till now through clicking the refresh button.